# Node Selection - Two Tags Deep from Current Node

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I am using HTML Agility Pack. I have an HTMLNode which has the following InnerHtml:

```
"Item: <b><a href="item.htm">Link Text</a></b>"
```

From this node, I want to select the "Link Text" from within the "a" tag. I have not been able to do this. I have tried this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(node.InnerHtml);
//The above line prints "Item: <b><a href="item.htm">Link Text</a></b>"
HtmlNode boldTag = node.SelectSingleNode("b");
if (boldTags != null)
{
    HtmlNode linkTag = boldTag.SelectSingleNode("a");
    //This is always null!
    if (linkTag != null)
    {
        return linkTag.InnerHtml;           
    }
}
```

Any help to get the selection correct would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectSingleNode expects an XPath

So you need

```
 var b = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//b");
 var a = b.SelectSingleNode("./a");
 var text = a.InnerText;
```

in one line

```
var text =  htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//b/a").InnerText;
```

Note that at the begining of the xpath

- // will look anywhere in DocumentNode
- .// will look for a descendant of the current node
- / will look for a child of the DocumentNode
- ./ will look for a child of the current node

Comment: @CamilleSévigny as far as i know it will only work if node is the DocumentNode

Comment: Not very clear until now. `a` and `b` are proper XPath expressions, and `./a` and `a` are the same in most contexts. `//b` selects `b` elements from anywhere in the document, not only in the small snippet the OP shows.